# Special romanian characters are not displaying properly when using the proxima nova font

Tags: html, wordpress, fonts

We use Proxima Nova as are default font on a wordpress site. When posting pages with romanian language, the special characters are not displayed correctly. See url https://exponential.eu/roundtables-2021/romania/

As you can see, characters like ă is more bold and have a higher font size than the rest of the normal characters. The special characters are falling back to the "fall back font", which is Verdana.

Proxima Nova should support Romanian characters, why are we experiencing this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Proxima Nova using Adobe Typekit. Solved it by setting the 'Character Set' from 'Default' (which includes English, French, German, Italian, Portuguese and Spanish) to 'Language Subsetting' and ticking those languages but also Romanian.

[image: Proxima Nova settings in Adobe Typekit to support Romanian]

Answer (score -1):

Put the special characters in a `span` element with a smaller font size. (line 389)

```
<p>Strada Halelor 5,<br />
Bucure<span style="font-size: 0.95em;">ș</span>ti 030167</p>
```

Comment: No. The special charactars are falling back to the fall-back font. Which in this case is Verdana. So the style will be different.